# Admob - Redirected to admob.com when creating a new Site/App

Tags: redirect, authentication, admob

I recently tried to add a new Site/App:

[image]

Afterwards I choose "Android App" and fill out (or don't fill out, it doesen't matter at this point) the form.
Afterwards I click the "Continue" button which should lead me to the next step - getting my "Site Code".
But instead of redirecting me there, I get redirected to `admob.com` and I'm logged out.
Brilliant.

By the way, I am using my google account to log in.
I tried different browsers, cleaned cookies/passwords - nothing helped :/.
I already have 4 active android apps there.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

But I would have a look at the publisher guidelines: https://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1307237&topic=1307235&ctx=topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out this has been a temporary bug with Admob.
It has been fixed today.